# Collapse/Expand Child Nodes

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts Organization Chart, is there a way to hide the people below. So for instance, if you have the CEO and 5 people report to them. Can I add a button to the CEO node that will hide all children once clicked? Even deeper if the CTO reports to the CEO but the CTO has 9 people report to her, can I hide the CTO children and the CEO? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared an example of how to hide/show nodes under the CEO node on custom Highcharts button. By using this logic you should be able to create the rest of the wanted collapse buttons.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7orp61kx/

Render responsive button on render event:

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      points = chart.series[0].points,
      ceoPoint = points[1].toNode,
      buttonX = ceoPoint.dataLabel.translateX,
      buttonY = ceoPoint.dataLabel.translateY + chart.plotTop;

    // check if button exist after window resize
    if (chart.ceoButton) {
      chart.ceoButton.destroy();
    }
    // create button 
    chart.ceoButton = chart.renderer.button('hide/show children', buttonX, buttonY, hideShow).add()
    // translate button
    chart.ceoButton.translate(buttonX - chart.ceoButton.getBBox().width, buttonY + chart.ceoButton.getBBox().height / 3)
  }
}
```

hideShow function:

```
function hideShow() {
  chart.series[0].points.forEach((p, i) => {
    if (i > 1) {
      if (p.state === "") {
        p.graphic.hide();
        p.toNode.graphic.hide();
        p.toNode.dataLabel.hide();

        p.state = 'hidden';
      } else {
        p.graphic.show();
        p.toNode.graphic.show();
        p.toNode.dataLabel.show();

        p.state = ""
      }
    }
  })
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, I was able to make this work. I was also wondering how to manipulate the labels that are on each node. Like can I add info that is displayed, like department or location, in addition to Name, Image, and title?

Comment: You can add that information in the name section, but you will need to decrease the chart height and nodeWidth properties, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2Lc5y1fq/